# Find Next Lower number based on other field in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table that has data like this:

```
MainID, MainNumber, MainType
1       250         Hours
2       500         Hours
3       1000        Hours
4       5000        Miles
5       20000       Miles
```

When I put the values in for the MainNumber and the MainType, I need to pull the next lower MainNumber for that MainType.

This is the code that I have:

```
SQL = "SELECT T2.MainID, Max([t2.MainNumber]) AS PreviousCycle"
SQL = SQL & " FROM tblMainType AS T1 LEFT JOIN tblMainType as T2 on T1.MainNumber > T2.MainNumber"
SQL = SQL & " WHERE T1.mainType = '" & mType & "' AND T1.MainNumber = " & MainNumber
SQL = SQL & " Group By T2.MainID;"
```

Oddly it works for hours but not miles? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: "Not works" doesn't give us much to work with.

Answer (score 0):

To find the next highest number I would take the sort the field in descending order and take `TOP 1` value.

```
Sql = "SELECT TOP 1 tblMainType.MainID, tblMainType.MainNumber " & _
      "FROM tblMainType " & _
      "WHERE (((tblMainType.MainNumber)< " & mType & ") AND ((tblMainType.MainType)='" & MainNumber & "')) " & _
      "ORDER BY tblMainType.MainNumber DESC;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MainID, MainNumber 
FROM tblMainType 
WHERE MainType = @MainType AND
      MainNumber >= @MainNumber
ORDER BY MainNumber DESC, MainId;
```

The `@MainType` and `@MainNumber` are the values you are inputting.